# NSDictionary loading binary plist on linux (swift)

Tags: linux, swift, macos

As the implementation of serverside swift is different, there is a fundamental (to my project) part of the `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` missing.
Namely the `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:` method loads only non-binary plist files on Linux so my app works only on macOS. There some older questions on StackOverflow answers re this topic, but they lead to sites that don't exist anymore.
So my question is: Is there any easy way to load binary plist into NSDictionary without having to use some "decompile" outside script and if there is no solution, what would be the most elegant solution using one?

Comment: Is there any reason why the plist has to be binary? Can you not [convert it into an XML plist](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Converting_Binary_Plists)? There is a library called [libplist](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist) that can do the job.

Comment: Yes, binary plist is coming from a compiled .ipa and I want to make the final product easy to install for the end client

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding native handling of .plists in `Swift` is via `PropertyListSerialization`:

```
// PropertyListSerialization Method

var plistFormat = PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.binary
let plistPath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "binary", ofType: "plist")!
let plistBinary = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: plistPath!)!

guard let propertyList = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistBinary, options: [], format: &plistFormat) else {
    fatalError("failed to deserialize")
}
print(propertyList as! [String:Any])
```

**Result:**

> `"["MyDictionary": {\n    MyArray =     (\n        Two,\n        One\n);\n}]\n"`

The `NSDictionary` way, as you know would likely be:

```
// NSDictionary Method

if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"binary", withExtension: "plist"),
    let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
    print(myDict)
}
```

**Result:**

> `"["MyDictionary": {\n    MyArray =     (\n        Two,\n        One\n);\n}]\n"`

Comparing the end result of both methods is identical using a `binary` .plist; I would imagine it should work (?), or at least give you some idea to an alternate means of reading/writing the data.

Comment: this is DESerialization, not Serialization. thank you for half, could you also add serializing a NSDictionary or [String: Encodable]

Answer (score 1):

If worst comes to worse, you can use [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org) to translate the binary plist to XML, save the xml in a temporary location, then load it in the Swift code.

You could try using CoreFoundation functions like `CFPropertyListCreateWithData`, but if Foundation methods aren't working, I doubt CoreFoundation would work, either.